# Better version of "Monotonicity methods in Hilbert spaces and some applications to nonlinear PDEs.."

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

I am asking whether any one knows of a better source for the text

> Monotonicity methods in Hilbert spaces and some applications to nonlinear partial differential
>   equations by H. Brezis

which I find painful to read due to the awful typewriter-style typesetting. Is there some modern book that covers this paper, in particular, Corollary 31, which I've posted :

> Corollary 31. All spaces are over the bounded domain $\Omega$. Let $u_0 \in H^{-1}$ and let $f:[0,T] \to H^{-1}$ be absolutely continuous. There exists a unique $u \in C([0,T];H^{-1})$ satisfying $t\beta(u) \in L^\infty(H^1_0)$, $tu_t \in L^\infty(H^{-1})$, $tu \in L^\infty(L^1)$, $u(x,t) \in L^1$, $\beta(u(x,t)) \in H^1_0$ for all $t$ satisfying
>   $$u_t - \Delta \beta(u) = f \quad \text{on $\Omega$}$$
>   $$\beta(u) = 0 \quad \text{on $\partial\Omega$}$$
>   $$u(x,0) =u_0\quad \text{on $\Omega$}$$